# I need to center wrapped text

Tags: html, css, formatting

I've wrapped text to better contain it, but it made it so that it is no longer centered; it's justified it to the left side of the page, but I need it to be centered.

I originally did not have the style section at all but figured I needed it in order to wrap my text since I didn't want the words spanning across the whole page just due to the nature of the content.

In short, I just need my content to be centered again, but I need the 430px wrapping of the text.

Thank you.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>contact</title>

    <body>
    <div class=“panel”>
    <center>
    <img src=img/about_blackonorange.png height=215 width=215>
    </center>

<center>        
<div class="twelve columns nav-bar--column">
<nav class="nav-collapse">


    <a href=home.html>home</a>
    <a href=news_v2.html>news</a>
    <a href=visual_v2.html>visual</a>
    <a href=audio_v2.html>audio</a>
    <a href=contact_v2.html>contact</a>
    <a href=about.html>about<a>


</nav>
</div> 
</center>

<style>
div {
    width: 430px;
    center;
    }
div.a {
    word-wrap: normal;
}

</style>

<!—-CONTENT GOES HERE—->

<center>
<p>
<div class="a">
blah blah blah blah blah. 
<br></br>
blah blah blah blah blah. 
</div>
</p>
</center>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: None of the answers that uses standard positioning center-aligns wrapped text perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

It should be text-align : center

```
div {
width: 430px;
text-align : center;
}
```

Here is a working example :

```css
div {
    width: 430px;
    text-align : center;
    }
div.a {
    word-wrap: normal;
```

```html
<title>contact</title>

    <body>
    <div class=“panel”>
    <center>
    <img src=img/about_blackonorange.png height=215 width=215>
    </center>

<center>        
<div class="twelve columns nav-bar--column">
<nav class="nav-collapse">


    <a href=home.html>home</a>
    <a href=news_v2.html>news</a>
    <a href=visual_v2.html>visual</a>
    <a href=audio_v2.html>audio</a>
    <a href=contact_v2.html>contact</a>
    <a href=about.html>about<a>


</nav>
</div> 
</center>



<!—-CONTENT GOES HERE—->

<center>
<p>
<div class="a">
blah blah blah blah blah. 
<br></br>
blah blah blah blah blah. 
</div>
</p>
</center>



    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS to your container:

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This centers the element to the middle of whatever wrapper is around it. If none, it just centers it to the middle of the screen.

As far as aligning text to the center of the element, you can add this CSS:

```
text-align: center;
```

Comment: Works for some scenarios, not practical in others where the parent might not be positioned explicitly.

Comment: @Epirocks do you mean *relative*? Or what do you mean by "positioned explicitly"?